# SoapUI Mock Response - Response Time

Tags: mocking, response, soapui

I am running a Mock Service which is running several different Mock Operations.

What I am finding however that the logged response times are taking several seconds, which seems a long time. If I eyeball the raw messages, they seem to be created instantly. I have also put timers in the dispatch script code which shows there are no delay there (the code runs in milliseconds).

Can somebody please advise if the logged response times in the Mock Operations log is purely the time it took to generate the response, or if this includes the network comms – i.e. that the response time includes sending the response back to the app? I’m struggling to pinpoint where the delay is.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I just did a quick local mock service.

I just let it return the same static response every time.

From the consumer endpoint, the response got there in around 7-11 ms.
This number was retrieved in a separate Groovy Script teststep by reading

```
 testRunner.testCase.testSteps["SOAP Request"].testRequest.response.timeTaken
```

From the mock side, reponse was produced in around 1 ms.
This was done in a AfterRequest script reading

```
mockResult.timeTaken
```

I also tried to include a `${= sleep(1000) }` in the response template. The diff remained about the same.

I don't think network time is included.

Comment: Thanks Steen, that makes sense. What I have discovered is that the delay is in parsing the variables within the soap response body. If I build the soap response within the groovy it takes milliseconds, whereas accessing the variables from the context within the SOAP response body seems to have a big overhead. Not sure if this is best practice, but it gets around the performance issues.